# How to handle a file having header in between the records after removing duplicates from the file

Tags: unix

We have a file which has been processed by unix command for removing duplicates. After the de-duplication new file has the header in-between the records. Please help to solve this and thanks in advance for inputs.

Unix Command : Sort -u  >

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
grep "headers" >output.txt
grep -v "headers" >>output.txt
```

The idea is the following: first take the headers and put them into output.txt, and afterwards take everything which is not a header and put it into that output file.

First you need to put the information in the output file (which means you need to create the output file, hence the single `>` character), secondly you need to append the information to the already existing output file (hence the double `>>` character).